# ASP.NET Core adding calculations in my properties model and having it as a column in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, properties

In ASP.NET Core, I have properties that are calculated based on other properties, for example, I have

```
public class Worker
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public double Rev {get;set;}
  public double Cost {get;set;}
  public double Profit {get;set;}
}
```

and `Profit` is meant to be `Rev - Cost` and for awhile I've been working on a problem where basically either calculations were not performed or the column would not exist. I would have in my `Create` action something like this

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Rev,Cost,Profit")] Worker worker)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       Worker employee = new Worker
       {
          Rev = worker.Rev,
          Cost = worker.Cost,
          Profit = worker.Rev - worker.Cost
       };
       _context.Add(employee);
       await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
       return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

By doing this, everything would show up in my database and look fine, however `Profit` would not be calculated and would be 0. If I change my controller and do not calculate `Profit` in the controller and instead calculate it in the model it all works like so

```
public class Worker{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public double Rev {get;set;}
    public double Cost {get;set;}

    public double Profit{
       get
          {
             return Rev - Cost;
          }
    }
}
```

It all works and the calculations are performed but `Profit` is not column in my `Worker` table. My Question is, how do I perform the calculations in the model but still save `Profit` as a column in the database, I need both a `get; set;` but I am not sure how to implement the `set` while performing and saving the calculations?

Comment: I think your controller is wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to introduce a backing field.  In your above example your model will end up looking something like this:

```
public class Worker
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Rev { get; set; }
    public double Cost { get; set; }

    private double _profit;
    public double Profit
    {
        get
        {
            return Rev - Cost;
        }
        set
        {
            _profit = value;
        }
    }
}
```

If you're using version 3.0+ of EF Core you'll need to tell EF to use the computed property rather than the backing field:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Worker>()
        .Property(e => e.Profit)
        .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Property);
}
```

Source: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18998

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I think I will try a different way however, I will keep this in my notes for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you create an [auto computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15) in the database table, so whenever you are inserting a new value for `Rev` and `Cost` columns the `Profit` column will be auto computed, like this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.Worker
ADD Profit AS Rev-Cost;
```

This way you will be able to insert `Rev` and `Cost` values to the table and not worry about calculation.
Later you will just read `Profit` value into your Model -> Profit property, the same way as you are reading other Properties from the `SQL` table.

Comment: I have attempted this before, but I was unsure how to do, thanks for showing me!

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution. I used the following Fluent AP. You can use the following code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Worker>()
        .Property(P => P.Profit)
        .HasComputedColumnSql("[Rev] - [Cost]");
}
```